# What's the name of the group of words which link sentences together?

Tags: grammar

For example, "within which," "of which," etc.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, "of which" is a prepositional phrase. But the term that you are likely looking for is **relative pronoun**. Look up:

- **relative pronouns:** *The most common relative pronouns are who/whom, whoever/whomever, whose, that, and which. (Please note that in certain situations, "what," "when," and "where" can function as relative pronouns.) Relative pronouns introduce relative clauses, which are a type of dependent clause. Relative clauses modify a word, phrase, or idea in the main clause. The word, phrase, or idea modified is called the antecedent.* ([Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/645/01/))

And also contrast with:

- **subordinating conjunctions:** *When a sentence has an independent clause (main clause) and at least one dependent clause, it is known as a complex sentence. In a complex sentence, the role of the subordinating conjunction and the dependent clause is to establish a time, a place, a reason, a condition, a concession, or a comparison for the main clause. The subordinating conjunction provides the bridge between the main clause and the dependent clause.* ([Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subordinating_conjunctions.htm))

Key difference is clearly articulated in Wikipedia:

> In linking a subordinate clause and a main clause, a relative pronoun functions similarly to a subordinating conjunction. Unlike a conjunction, however, a relative pronoun does not simply mark the subordinate (relative) clause, but also plays the role of a noun within that clause.

**Links:**

- [Relative pronouns on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun)
- [Relative pronouns on Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/645/01/)
- [Subordinating conjunctions on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Subordinating_conjunctions)
- [Subordinating conjunctions on Grammar Bytes](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateconjunction.htm)

Comment: "Within which", "of which", "in which" etc. are preposition phrases, of course, but it's useful to call them 'relative phrases'. But it's only the relative pronoun "which" that is anaphorically related to the head noun.

Comment: Conjuction junction, what's your function? That's all I can think about now... It's a song a song, for those who don't, know called "Conjunction Junction" from the show School House Rock.